# Subquery with average aggregate issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have to use a subquery to find out which items sold with a greater than average price, but i keep getting an error at the end and i have been staring at it too long i know I’m close could i get a bump in the right direction.
someone who knows what’s up please?

I have this currently:

```
select oi.OrderID
     , ItemID
     , oi.price
from ORDERS o join ORDER_ITEM oi
     on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
where oi.price >
 (select avg(oi.price) from ORDER_ITEM)
```

Comment: You should tell us what error message you are getting.

Comment: I think this is a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an outer reference in the aggregation.  Use different table aliases for the subquery:

```
select oi.OrderID, ItemID, oi.price
from ORDERS o join
     ORDER_ITEM oi
     on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
where oi.price > (select avg(oi2.price) from ORDER_ITEM oi2);
-----------------------------^
```

Your version is taking the average of `price` from the *outer* reference.  Some databases (notably SQL Server, but perhaps others) do not allow this.

I should also note that the join seems superfluous:

```
select oi.OrderID, oi.ItemID, oi.price
from ORDER_ITEM oi
where oi.price > (select avg(oi2.price) from ORDER_ITEM oi2);
```